# Get запрос к динамическому сайту возвращает код JS. Как достать данные?

Tags: javascript, python, html, requests, beautiful-soup

На сайте с динамической загрузкой есть данные, которые, как я понял подгружаются по ходу работы сайта (то есть при обновлении вкладки 1 get запрос возвращает страницу, в которой нет необходимых данных). Глядя на запросы, которые выполняются позже, я вижу, что многие из них возвращают JS код. Я не понимаю как он вообще запускается и зачем они его возвращают. Предположительно эти запросы вызывают появление предполагаемой мне информации.

Так вот вопрос, как мне понять как JS скрипт изменяет html страницы, так, чтобы на нем появились необходимые мне данные.

Второй вопрос: как мне получить эти данные? Может надо этому скрипту передать уже загруженный html, может пошаманить с скриптом. Если да, то подскажите как.

Comment: вы не в состоянии посмотреть содержи ответ данные или нет? или что?

Comment: Шаманить это на битву экстрасенсов. Здесь вам помогут с конкретными примерами.

Comment: @teran На странице, которая отображается у меня в браузере есть необходимые мне данные, в одном из html тегов. Среди запросов которые отправляет сервер нет того, который возвращает html документ с этими данными, но есть те, которые возвращают JS код. Из JS кода я не в состоянии посмотреть данные

Comment: какой сайт и какие данные нужны?

Comment: Используйте `headless` браузеры, на подобии `selenium`.

Comment: маловероятно, что текст там как-то закодирован в ответе. поэтому просто текстовым поиском найдите в подгружаемом контенте нужные слова текста среди того, что асинхронно подгружается скриптами.

Answer (score 0):

Я все получше изучил, и оказалось, что это не те запросы. Необходимая мне информация передается с помощью XHR. Так что приношу свои извинения за беспокойство.

Если вы столкнулись с такой же ошибкой - посмотрите повнимательнее запросы браузера